# how to simplify template?

Tags: html, angularjs

how to simplify template in angularjs? Here there are three different variants lie within podgruzki data objects, but depending on different objects IF loaded with different sets of properties. Is it possible to simplify both the template

```
<div class="suggest" ng-show="showSuggest" ng-if="$ctrl.Name == 'A'">
    <ul class="height-list">
        <li ng-repeat="node in $ctrl.Searched()"  ng-mousedown="add(this)">
            <span ng-attr-title="{{node.a}}">{{node.a}}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="suggest" ng-show="showSuggest" ng-if="$ctrl.Name == 'B'">
    <ul class="height-list">
        <li ng-repeat="node in $ctrl.Searched() "  ng-mousedown="add(this)">
            <span ng-attr-title="{{node.b}}">{{node.b}}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="suggest" ng-show="showSuggest" ng-if="$ctrl.Name == 'C'">
    <ul class="height-list">
        <li ng-repeat="node in $ctrl.Searched()"  ng-mousedown="add(this)">
            <span ng-attr-title="{{node.C}}">{{node.C}}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you normalize your `node` and `name` to be 1 to 1. So if your controller name is "a" or "Foo", then your `node` will have a property named `a` or `Foo`.

Then you will be able to reduce your template to the following:

```
<div class="suggest" ng-show="showSuggest">
    <ul class="height-list">
        <li ng-repeat="node in $ctrl.Searched()"  ng-mousedown="add(this)">
            <span ng-attr-title="{{node[$ctrl.Name]}}">{{node[$ctrl.Name]}}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: No do not get a lot of different properties.

Comment: Yes, that is the M in MVC.

Comment: @Vladimir, can you expand on what you mean by: `No do not get a lot of different properties.`?

Comment: If you need to keep the 'Name's and properties as they are in your example "A", "B", "C"  for names and `a`, `b`, `C` for properties, you can create a simple map: `YourController.prototype.nameMap =  {"A": "a", "B": "b", "C": "C"};` Then in the view you would do `{{node[$ctrl.nameMap[$ctrl.Name]]}}`